# Cant Call jQuery in PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

When I'm using jQuery in HTML,it works fine.But it doesnt work when I echo  in PHP.It should do dropdown when I want to read the content.

[image: a busy cat]

Here how it looks like.Now I want to click "View" and it should show the content:

[image: a busy cat]

blog.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $('#drop').click(function()
                {
                    $('.post').slideToggle('fast');
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>



    <div id="contain">
        <div id="banner">
        </div>
        <div id="blogposts">
            <?php
            include 'constr.php';
            $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * from blog LIMIT 10");
            while($read = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $yazar = $read["yazarAdi"];
                $baslik = $read["baslik"];
                $tarih = $read["tarih"];
                $icerik = $read["icerik"];
                echo '
                    <div id="postcontain">
                    <table class="info">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p style=" font-style:Italic;">'.$yazar.'</p> <td><p style="text-align:right; padding-right:10px;  font-style:Italic;">'.$tarih.'</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p style="padding-bottom:5px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;">'.$baslik.'</p></td>
                            <td style="text-align:right;"><a id="drop">View</a></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                    '.$icerik.'
                    </div>
                ';
            }
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Related to the content:

```
.post
{
background-color:White;
width:800px;
box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 100px 5px #ccc;
border-top:3px solid #ffc;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: and the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure your data is visible to the client so jQuery can run successfully?

Comment: Data passes successfully when you remove display:none;

Comment: the post element is in `$icerik` variable?

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes

Comment: @KorayBallı see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The click must slide an element that have class `post` :

```
$('.post').slideToggle('fast');
```

And you're missing to add elements with this class to your code.

The `id` attributes should be unique in the same document so you've to change the `id`'s you've in your loop to classes e.g: `drop` and `postcontain`.

**NOTE :** If you've the posts in your code, the js that you've now will slide all the posts in the same time, so it may you want to go up to the parent `postcontain` then toggle the post inside, using :

```
$(this).closest('.postcontain').find('.post').slideToggle('fast');
```

**Full JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.drop').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.postcontain').find('.post').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant!But now it does do that only to first post.When I click the others,they dont work

Comment: It should works if the div `postcontain` is the parent of every post.

Comment: Yep the problem was,I used id instead of class.It works now,thanks

Comment: @KorayBallı this is the complete answer that cover the `id`'s duplication and that should be accepted.

Comment: I wish I could accept 2 of the posts.Again thank you Zakaria and Madalin.The reason why I accepted Madalin's one is because he were the first to respond it.And since his solution was the shorter and appropriate for my practise

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest+next+find` to select the element relative to your clicked tab

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
    {
      $('.info a').click(function()
       {
         $(this).closest('.info').next().find('.post').slideToggle('fast');
       });
    });
```

Consider using classes instead of ids

Comment: Magically, when I changed #drop  to  .info a ,it worked.Thanks!'

Answer (score 0):

I prefer that you separate PHP code from HTML, to make it clean and readable, you can create a new php file to get data from you databse json format :

Create **data.php**

```
<?php
include 'constr.php';
$query = mysqli_query( $connect, "SELECT * from blog LIMIT 10" );

$blog = [];
while ( $read = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
    $item = array(
        "yazarAdi" => $read["yazarAdi"],
        "baslik"   => $read["baslik"],
        "tarih"    => $read["tarih"],
        "icerik"   => $read["icerik"],
    );
    array_push( $blog, $item );
}

echo json_encode( $blog );
```

On your HTML :

- To include JS use `<script>` tags.
- `id=""` should be used once per page, else you can replace with `class=""`
- To understand the logic of your problem, your `$('#drop').click` is called before that php put links`<a id="drop">View</a>` on your page, so event is not binded to those links.

I maked a quick example for an HTML that use the file **data.php** file, you can adapte on your way :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contain">
    <div id="banner">
    </div>
    <div id="blogposts">
        <div id="postcontain">
            <table id="mytable" class="info">

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("data.php", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                var item = '<tr>' +
                    '<td><p>' + val['yazar'] + '</p> <td><p>' + val['tarih'] + '</p></td>' +
                    '</tr>';

                item += '<tr>' +
                    '<td><p>' + val['baslik'] + '</p></td>' +
                    '<td><a href="#" class="drop" data-yazar="' + val['yazar'] + '">View</a></td>' +
                    '</tr>';

                $("#mytable").append(item);

            });

            $('.drop').click(function () {
                alert("drop clicked at : " + $(this).data('yazar'));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Somes explanations :

- `$.getJSON("data.php"` call our new page to get data on json format.
- `$.each(data, function (key, val) {` fetch our data item per item.
- `$("#mytable").append(item);` add rows `<tr>` to our table  `<table id="mytable"`
- On the view links `<a href="#" class="drop" data-yazar=`, I addad a `data-yazar` attribute to identify which link will be clicked using `$(this).data('yazar')` on click function, you can put your item id for example.

Comment: Unnecessary double up requests just for the sake of 'better' code readability. However, better depends on personal opinion here. Bad suggestion, sorry.

Comment: The main problem is to bind click on items that is not loaded yet, the good way is to load data (ajax?) then bind click to links (on its success).

Comment: Having PHP files seperetaly means doubling the request.Everything should be happening on the client-side.Thats why JS/Jquery is probably the best way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of echoing all the HTML close the PHP tag `?>` above it and open it again below after HTML code `<?PHP` and variables in HTML must be in `<?=$var?>`

**Like:**

```
<?php while ($something): ?>

  <div class='Foo'>
    Bar
  </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `id="drop"` to `class="drop"`

Hense jQuery will be `$(".drop")` to pick up on that class.